# endless reboot of ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, cron, reboot

I use Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with [bigbluebutton](https://bigbluebutton.org/).

Yesterday at 8 am, ubuntu started to reboot uncontrollably every 9:27 minutes.

I searched the Internet in a search engine, did everything possible, and even tried to disable shutdown, halt, power off, reboot.

Everything I found and think is suspicious:

```
root@bbb-server:/home/user# cat /var/log/syslog | grep reboot
Sep 30 08:02:10 bbb-server kernel: [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Sep 30 08:02:10 bbb-server kernel: [    0.011109] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Sep 30 08:02:10 bbb-server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu Advantage reboot cmds being skipped.
Sep 30 08:02:10 bbb-server cron[975]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Sep 30 08:09:29 bbb-server kernel: [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Sep 30 08:09:29 bbb-server kernel: [    0.011132] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Sep 30 08:09:29 bbb-server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu Advantage reboot cmds being skipped.
Sep 30 08:09:29 bbb-server cron[932]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Binary file (standard input) matches

root@bbb-server:/home/user# last -x | head
user     pts/0        IP               Sat Sep 30 21:08   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 21:07   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 20:59   still running
user     pts/0        IP               Sat Sep 30 20:58 - crash  (00:08)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 20:57   still running
user     pts/0        IP               Sat Sep 30 20:56 - crash  (00:01)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 20:55 - 20:59  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 20:54   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-163-generi Sat Sep 30 20:38 - 20:55  (00:17)
```

Please tell me what else can be used to block this problem, even if it harms Ubuntu management.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried applying all security fixes & upgrades; details in your question imply strongly that you have not (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded before that date)

Comment: Look at the `@reboot` `cron` jobs in the system crontab, `/etc/crontab`, and the user crontabs `/var/spool/cron/*`. Check `/var/spool/at/*`. too. See the last of the previous boot's logs with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`.

Comment: Hi @guiverc, I have not done any updates since the installation, as I am afraid that the system that is installed on ubuntu will not survive this. I use as written in the Ubuntu welcome:
`Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-163-generic x86_64)`

Comment: Hi @waltinator, thanks for your `/etc/crontab`, there is nothing, in addition to the usual tasks for the day, week, and so on, I also looked at them, there is nothing there except for standard created tasks or service.
In the folder `/var/spool/cron/` and the subfolders are empty, there are no files there.
I executed the command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`.

Comment: @waltinator, I would like to leave a link to the file in google drive, but I don't know if it's possible here, but I didn't see anything there, the latest logs:
```Oct 01 17:25:43 bbb-server su[3179]: (to root) user on pts/0
Oct 01 17:25:43 bbb-server su[3179]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=1000)
Oct 01 17:25:48 bbb-server sudo[3188]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b -1 -e
Oct 01 17:25:48 bbb-server sudo[3188]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=0)```

Comment: @waltinator, that is, while I was reading the logs, he just made a poweroff, then there is nothing after these logs.
I have suspicions that this is a physical breakdown, but this is a server and I can safely go to the server's IPMI http site and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the power supply, I don't know why it restarted after 10 minutes.